# How to set existing bar chart styles to pivot chart in java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, pivot-table, pivot-chart

I am looking for a way to use apache poi to add existing default styles to a bar chart in Excel.
I have code to generate bar chart but could not find anything to set existing styles which are available in Chart Design --> Styles

Below is the current bar chart
[image]

Expected outcome
[image]

Below is the sample code I am running.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFChart;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.chart.*;

public class BarChart {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Workbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
        Sheet sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");

        Row row;
        Cell cell;

        row = sheet.createRow(0);
        row.createCell(0);
        row.createCell(1).setCellValue("HEADER 1");
        row.createCell(2).setCellValue("HEADER 2");
        row.createCell(3).setCellValue("HEADER 3");

        for (int r = 1; r < 5; r++) {
            row = sheet.createRow(r);
            cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue("Serie " + r);
            cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(new java.util.Random().nextDouble());
            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue(new java.util.Random().nextDouble());
            cell = row.createCell(3);
            cell.setCellValue(new java.util.Random().nextDouble());
        }

        XSSFDrawing drawing = (XSSFDrawing)sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
        ClientAnchor anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 8, 20);

        XSSFChart chart = drawing.createChart(anchor);

        CTChart ctChart = ((XSSFChart)chart).getCTChart();
        CTPlotArea ctPlotArea = ctChart.getPlotArea();
        CTBarChart ctBarChart = ctPlotArea.addNewBarChart();
        CTBoolean ctBoolean = ctBarChart.addNewVaryColors();
        ctBoolean.setVal(true);
        ctBarChart.addNewBarDir().setVal(STBarDir.BAR);

        for (int r = 2; r < 6; r++) {
           CTBarSer ctBarSer = ctBarChart.addNewSer();
           CTSerTx ctSerTx = ctBarSer.addNewTx();
           CTStrRef ctStrRef = ctSerTx.addNewStrRef();
           ctStrRef.setF("Sheet1!$A$" + r);
           ctBarSer.addNewIdx().setVal(r-2);  
           CTAxDataSource cttAxDataSource = ctBarSer.addNewCat();
           ctStrRef = cttAxDataSource.addNewStrRef();
           ctStrRef.setF("Sheet1!$B$1:$D$1"); 
           CTNumDataSource ctNumDataSource = ctBarSer.addNewVal();
           CTNumRef ctNumRef = ctNumDataSource.addNewNumRef();
           ctNumRef.setF("Sheet1!$B$" + r + ":$D$" + r);

           //at least the border lines in Libreoffice Calc ;-)
           ctBarSer.addNewSpPr().addNewLn().addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(new byte[] {0,0,0});   

        } 

        //telling the BarChart that it has axes and giving them Ids
        ctBarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123456);
        ctBarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123457);

        //cat axis
        CTCatAx ctCatAx = ctPlotArea.addNewCatAx(); 
        ctCatAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123456); //id of the cat axis
        CTScaling ctScaling = ctCatAx.addNewScaling();
        ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
        ctCatAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
        ctCatAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.B);
        ctCatAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123457); //id of the val axis
        ctCatAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);

        //val axis
        CTValAx ctValAx = ctPlotArea.addNewValAx(); 
        ctValAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123457); //id of the val axis
        ctScaling = ctValAx.addNewScaling();
        ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
        ctValAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
        ctValAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.L);
        ctValAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123456); //id of the cat axis
        ctValAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);

        //legend
        CTLegend ctLegend = ctChart.addNewLegend();
        ctLegend.addNewLegendPos().setVal(STLegendPos.B);
        ctLegend.addNewOverlay().setVal(false);

System.out.println(ctChart);

        FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream("BarChart.xlsx");
        wb.write(fileOut);
        fileOut.close();
        Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("BarChart.xlsx"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Run your code. Unzip the `BarChart.xlsx`. Have a look into `/xl/charts/chart1.xml`. Store the XML somewhere to have it later for comparison. Open `BarChart.xlsx` in Excel GUI and apply the chart design. Save `BarChart.xlsx`. Unzip the `BarChart.xlsx`. Have a look into `/xl/charts/chart1.xml` and compare with the previous stored XML. What has been changed? Was it only one single setting? What is your conclusion?